# .htaccess parse url works on localhost but gets redirect loop on VPS host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to parse urls with .htaccess and pull our either 1 or 2 parameters to load content based on the url.

If only the first url param (site.com/param1) is present then that's fine and should route to index.php?c=param but could also be (site.com/param1/param2) and get routed to index.php?c=param1&p=param2

It works perfectly on MAMP PRO running on Mavericks but when I clone the repo onto our VPS I get a redirect loop. There is an admin area for the site so I need to ignore the any url that follows the pattern

site.com/admin

The "parsable" urls follow this pattern

site.com/param1

or

site.com/param1/param2

The .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## SEO REWRITES ###
RewriteRule ^(admin) - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&e=$2

## URL PARSE ##

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$  /index.php?c=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  /index.php?c=$1&p=$2
</IfModule>
```

I'm lost but I feel like I'm missing something simple here. The most confusing part is that it has worked since development began. Anyone have any ideas as to why the redirect loop when running on an vps with apache but not on localhost or more importantly how to get it parsing on the live server.

Im now using this which works except when the trailing slash is missing from the url, then it breaks, Ive tried dif variations to let it match without a trailing slash but i just get 404's or internal server errors:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

```
RewriteRule ^(admin) - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&e=$2


RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  /index.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/$  /index.php?c=$1&p=index [L,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

## SEO REWRITES ###
RewriteRule ^(admin) - [L]

RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&e=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

## URL PARSE ##

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  /index.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$  /index.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I still get a redirect loop on the live server. I'm completely lost as to why, all the pieces are in place and seem correct. Also it works perfectly on localhost.

Comment: It is very difficult to provide an explanation/answer just based on this comment. Which URL is causing looping? What is DocumentRoot value of live server? What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: I uploaded this to a dif server and it works fine. Marking this answer as correct since the issue seems to be server config related.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the new problem, which seems minor.

Comment: You need to place first rule in my answer to ignore all files/directories as your very first rule.

Comment: Doesnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve on live server? Is is looping?

Comment: the looping is fixed. I need to match domain.com/param1 or domain.com/param1/ <--- with or without trailing slash

Comment: Every rule I suggested above has `/?$` in the end, that is used to match trailing slash. You need to have similar pattern in your rules too.

Comment: add RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?c=$1&p=index [L,QSA] as gthe last rule and it works. Thanks for all the assistance I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$  /index.php?c=$1
```

matches

```
index.php?c=blah
```

You need to add a rule so that any valid paths are served without modification.

Try adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

just after `RewriteEngine on`